# React - fetch from API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

Suppose I have this fetch call.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("apiUrl", {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => 
      response.json())
      .then((data) => {
          //setData(data);
          console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

When I do console.log about data, I am getting

```
[{"Column1Name":"value1","Column2Name":"value2", ...},{"Column1Name":"value1","Column2Name":"value2", ...},...}
```

as a string, not as an array of JSON objects. What could be the problem?

Comment: I think you're misunderstood. Kindly check `console.log(typeof data)`.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem from backend json generate.